# @interface UIViewController <What Are These Things Called> {

Tags: objective-c, methods, interface, delegates

What are the things in `<`here`>` called in a .h file after you declare the interface...

Example (The `UIWebViewDelegate` part):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called "protocols". The syntax declares that the class conforms to that particular protocol, ie. it implements not only the methods declared in the `ViewController` class interface, but also the methods declared in the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol. An Objective C *protocol* is conceptually similar to a Java *interface*. There's a more complete description of protocols at  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Answer (score 1):

They are called [protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html). And they specify what methods your class does or may implement. They are useful for things like delegates because when you write a class that needs a delegate, you usually want to be sure that the delegate implements all of the methods you need. You can ensure this by defining a protocol for your delegate and only allowing your delegate to be an object that implements that protocol.

Answer (score 1):

They are the protocols. When you declare them between the '<' and the '>' it means "the class conforms to this/these protocols>. A protocol is a set of methods that this class must implement. There are required methods (so the compiler will warn you if you don't implement them) and optional methods (that you can implement only if you want). Then you can declare a variable of type id. This means the id variable can store a pointer to an object of a class that implements this protocol, or nil.